# Suricata cygwin configuration libnet

Tags: cygwin, libnet, suricata

I am trying to install Suricata on Cygwin for Windows but when I run the ./configure I get the Warning libnet version 1.1.x could not be found. Does anyone know how to fix this because I cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Build and install libnet.
Latest source are available here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/libnet-dev/files/